# Erro ao executar e mostrar exclusão de um id no banco de dados usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo dificuldades ao executar a exclusão de um pessoas no banco de dados do MySQL usando o ID, **mas ele não executa a exclusão pois o ID digitado para exclusão ainda continua no banco e não mostra na página em PHP**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Excluir </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="excluir_cliente.php">
        <p> Nome do ID: <input type="text" name="id_cliente" size=30> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Eliminar"> </p>
        <p> <a href="aluno.php"> Formulário aluno </a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Remover </title> 
</head>
<body> 
    <h2> Remover cliente </h2>
    <?php
        $codrem = $_GET['id_cliente'];
        if (!$codrem) {
            echo 'Volte atrás e escreva o código do cliente a remover.'; 
        }
        echo "Cliente a remover: $codrem. <p>";
        $ligax = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');
        if (!$ligax){
            echo "<p> Falha na ligação."; exit; 
        }
        mysqli_select_db($ligax, 'aluno');
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        $result = mysqli_query($ligax, $consulta);
        $nr_antes = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $remove = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = '%$codrem%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($ligax, $remove);

        if ($result==0) echo "<p> Não removido <br>";

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        $result = mysqli_query($ligax, $consulta);
        $nr_depois = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $nr_removidos = $nr_antes - $nr_depois;
        echo 'Nº de registos removidos: '.$nr_removidos;
    ?>
<p> <a href="listar.php"> Listar registos </a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma funcionalidade que realizar este trabalho para você, não precisa pegar a diferença para subtrair e obter um resulta.
A função a ser utilizada é esta:

```
 mysqli_affected_rows($ligax)
```

Portanto seu html deve ficar assim:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Remover </title> 
</head>
<body> 
    <h2> Remover cliente </h2>
    <?php
        $codrem = $_GET['id_cliente'];
        if (!$codrem) {
            echo 'Volte atrás e escreva o código do cliente a remover.'; 
        }
        echo "Cliente a remover: $codrem. <p>";
        $ligax = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');
        if (!$ligax){
            echo "<p> Falha na ligação."; exit; 
        }
        $remove = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = '%$codrem%'";
        $result = mysqli_real_query($ligax, $remove);
        if ($result == FALSE) echo "<p> Não removido <br>";
        else echo 'Nº de registos removidos: '. mysqli_affected_rows($ligax);
    ?>
<p> <a href="listar.php"> Listar registos </a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Isso não deu certo e está exibindo ```Não removido```.

Comment: realmente ocorreu a delete na base de dados, pois olhando seu delete esta errado colocar %

Comment: outra coisa q possa ser é a sua função mysqli_query, ela é utilizada para SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN e não para delete. Você pode substituir por mysqli_real_query($ligax, $remove), que retornará TRUE e FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Analisando seu código:

```
$remove = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = '%$codrem%'";
```

Esse trecho parece ser o problema:

> '%$codrem%'

caso isso **$codrem** seja uma variável com o id o correto seria:

```
$remove = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = ".$codrem;
```

Comment: O problema foi resolvido e o ID desejado foi apagado, obg.